# Compare Two Values in different columns

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, compare

I have this worksheet and i need to compare the "venda" values with "esperado".
If Vendas > Esperado i need to paint the status cell with green, if Vendas < Esperado it will be red

[image]

Is there a way to make this process entirely on vba? I am still learning this tool

Comment: I did no coding so far, dont know so much of vba

Comment: Have you tried conditional formatting? You don't need any VBA for that.

Comment: i've tried that, but i'm thinking if there is a way it can be done full by vba

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, use the next code. It will create two `Union` ranges (for each cell interior color type), according to the required condition and color their interior at the code end, at once. That's  why it will be fast enough for reasonable ranges number of rows. If huge ranges, I can supply a different solution:

```
Sub PaintCells()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, rngGreen As Range, rngRed As Range, i As Long
 
 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 arr = sh.Range("B2:C" & lastR).Value2
 
 For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
    If arr(i, 1) > arr(i, 2) Then
            addURange rngGreen, sh.Range("D" & i + 1)
    ElseIf arr(i, 1) < arr(i, 2) Then
            addURange rngRed, sh.Range("D" & i + 1)
    End If
 Next i
 If Not rngGreen Is Nothing Then rngGreen.Interior.Color = vbGreen
 If Not rngRed Is Nothing Then rngRed.Interior.Color = vbRed
End Sub

Sub addURange(rngU As Range, rngAdd As Range)
    If rngU Is Nothing Then
        Set rngU = rngAdd
    Else
        Set rngU = Application.Union(rngU, rngAdd)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please ,what is `addURange` means in your answer !

Comment: @Waleed It was a `Sub` creating the `Union` range. It looks I deleted it by mistake when made an edit... Otherwise, I cannot understand how the code works. Except the case when I also post (for OP) a solution involving such a `Sub` and it happened to have it. Anyhow, I edited the answer and put it in the right place...

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub ValiaFuncionario()

Dim tables As Range

Set table = Range("B8", Range("B8").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown))

For Each Row In table.Rows

If Row.Cells(1, 2).Value < Row.Cells(1, 3) Then
    Row.Cells(1, 4).Interior.Color = vbRed
    Row.Cells(1, 4).Value = "ABAIXO"
Else
    Row.Cells(1, 4).Interior.Color = vbGreen
    Row.Cells(1, 4).Value = "ACIMA"
End If

Next Row

End Sub
```

i did like this and it worked